# How to convert SML/NJ HTML4 representation to a string

Tags: sml, smlnj, mlton

When using SML/NJ library's HTML4 library, how do I convert the Standard ML representation of HTML4 into a string?

For example, if I have the HTML representation below, what function can I use to get a string similar to `<html><head><title>Example</title></head><body><h1>Hello!</h1></body></html>`?

```ml
(* CM.make "$/html4-lib.cm"; *)
open HTML4;
val myHTML = HTML {
  version=NONE,
  head=[Head_TITLE ([], [PCDATA "Example"])],
  content=BodyOrFrameset_BODY (BODY ([], [
    BlockOrScript_BLOCK (H1 ([], [CDATA [PCDATA "Hello!"]]))]))
};
```

(SML/NJ version: 110.99.2)

Comment: I was not able to find any documentation on this library, but [this](https://smlnj-gforge.cs.uchicago.edu/scm/viewvc.php/smlnj-lib/trunk/HTML4/html4-printer.sml?view=markup&revision=3985&root=smlnj&sortby=author) _might_ be useful.

Comment: @Chris I don't think the `HTML4Printer` structure is useful because it is not listed in [`html4-lib.cm`](https://smlnj-gforge.cs.uchicago.edu/scm/viewvc.php/smlnj-lib/trunk/HTML4/html4-lib.cm?view=markup&root=smlnj&sortby=author), which means that I am not able to access it from the code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [SML/NJ bug tracker](https://github.com/smlnj/legacy/issues/65), the following function can be used to convert `HTML4.html` to a string:

```ml
fun toString html =
  let
    val buf = CharBuffer.new 1024
  in
    HTML4Print.prHTML {
      putc = fn c => CharBuffer.add1 (buf, c),
      puts = fn s => CharBuffer.addVec (buf, s)
    } html;
    CharBuffer.contents buf
  end
```

To be able to use `HTML4Print.prHTML` in the SML/NJ REPL, the REPL should be started using `sml '$/html4-lib.cm'`. Alternatively, enter `CM.make "$/html4-lib.cm";` after starting the REPL.

The function has signature `val toString = fn : HTML4.html -> CharBuffer.vector`. `CharBuffer` is an extension to the Basis Library (reference: [2018 001 Addition of monomorphic buffers](https://github.com/SMLFamily/BasisLibrary/wiki/2018-001-Addition-of-monomorphic-buffers)). `CharBuffer.vector` is the same type as `CharVector.vector`, which is the same type as `String.string`, which is the same type as `string`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you could use the `HTML4Print` structure (which appears in [the export list in the CM file](https://smlnj-gforge.cs.uchicago.edu/scm/viewvc.php/smlnj-lib/trunk/HTML4/html4-lib.cm?view=markup&root=smlnj&sortby=author)):

```
$ sml '$/html4-lib.cm'
Standard ML of New Jersey (64-bit) v110.99.2 [built: Thu Sep 23 13:44:44 2021]
[library $/html4-lib.cm is stable]
- open HTML4Print;
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-LIB/Util/smlnj-lib.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
opening HTML4Print
  val prHTML : {putc:char -> unit, puts:string -> unit} -> HTML4.html -> unit
  val prBODY : {putc:char -> unit, puts:string -> unit} -> HTML4.body -> unit
```

So, with your value, it produces:

```
- HTML4Print.prHTML { putc = print o String.str, puts = print } myHTML;
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
Example
</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Hello!</H1>
</BODY>
</HTML>
val it = () : unit
```

Comment: Note that I do not want to print the HTML. I only want to get it as a string. I am looking for `HTML4.html -> string`, not `HTML4.html -> unit`.

Comment: @Flux I see. Indeed, it doesn't seem to expose anything that would let you do that, so I'd just go ahead and provide custom `putc` and `puts` functions above, functions that would write to some string buffer. Not ideal, but it's possible at least.